# Empty space coming before table row when an another element in row with rowspan has bigger data

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have created a table in which first 3 columns are spanning to multiple rows. Now when the data in any of the first three columns is smaller then the problem is not there, but if the data is bigger and rows are not spanning to many rows then there is empty space coming above the rest of the columns.

[image]

Comment: send html script.

Comment: HTML is pretty simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A)**

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.child-tbl{
border:0;
}
.child-tbl td{
  border:0;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="main">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:50px;">3</td>
    <td style="width:50px;">39</td>
    <td style="width:250px;">
        x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align:top;">
      <table class="child-tbl">
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**B)**

Also I made a mix of css codes that with it fit the height of right cells to its container. I user `height:1px` for the `table` container (`div`) and `height:100%` for `table`:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
}
table th{
  background:#0095ff;
  color:#fff;
  height:50px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.child-tbl{
  border:0;
}
.child-tbl td{
  border:0;
  border-bottom:1px solid #bbb;
  height:50%;
}
.child-tbl tr:last-child td{
  border-bottom:0;
}
.child-tbl td:first-child{
  border-right:1px solid #bbb;
}
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
div{
  height:1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="main">
    <tr>
      <th style="width:50px;">Col 1</th>
      <th style="width:50px;">Col 2</th>
      <th style="width:150px;">Col 3</th>
      <th>
        <table class="child-tbl">
            <tr>
              <td style="width:50px;">Col 4</td>
              <td>Col 5</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:50px;">3</td>
      <td style="width:50px;">39</td>
      <td style="width:150px;">
          x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align:top;">
        <table class="child-tbl">
          <tr>
            <td style="width:50px;">6</td>
            <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing a solution. It is a great workaround and I implemented it, many thanks. However, now the problem is how should i adjust the headers of the table to align properly to the innner table elements.

Comment: @DevSingh, I updated my answer with a solution for table header. Run the second code in my answer again.

Comment: Thanks again, will try and let you know in sometime.