# Firefox issue with RTL and relative table cell

Tags: css, firefox

I have the following code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #afafaf;
}

.content {
  width: 500px;
}

.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

table tr td {
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
}

.row-odd {
  background-color: #ff4e4e;
}

.row-even {
  background-color: #5bfc7a;
}
```

```html
<div class="content rtl">
  <table>
    <tr class="row-odd">
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-even">
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

In Firefox(versions: 55/56/57/58) the result is:
[image]

In Chrome I see the following:
[image]

Issue occurs when TD cell has "position: relative" attribute assigned, when removed the table is rendered correctly in both browsers.
I need this "position: relative" for table cell due to other features that will be used.

Does anybody have any idea how to correct this problem ?

Comment: Ouu yes, It seems damaged in FF. OK, now why you want `position: relative` over `td` elements? Do you have a element in a `td` that its position is `absolute`? or what? Anyway I added an answer that let you have a `div` (container) in the `td` elements that has `relative` position.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug

https://jsfiddle.net/32e7sz2e/

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table tr td {
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

I have added some border to show you where the table is, it's funny if I inspect and set text-align: right, the table will correct itself. Probably some kind display issue with FF.

If you need position relative, then add a wrapper inside of the cell and set it to relative

https://jsfiddle.net/32e7sz2e/1/

```
  <td>
    <div>
      Cell 1
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>
      Cell 2
    </div>
  </td>
```

Comment: Note **any** `text-align` value seems to resolve this (at least when i tried).

Comment: It only resolved it for me when I use inspect, when I load the fiddle with the props again, it does not work. I am on Mac. if it works for windows then cheers

Comment: Hmmm...didn't try it that way. Definitely feels like a bug

Comment: Yea you can probably add any prop in inspector and it will show correctly, I just tried adding text-transform and it corrects itself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Problem with inner div is that it won't fill the entire height of a cell, unless the table height is explicitly specified and in my case the table height depends on the content.

Comment: @ArturoO you can add `height: 100%` for the div, but in most cases you probably won't even need it as the background colour can still stay on the `td`. Any position absolute items inside of the div you can use top as your reference point. When all else fails, set height to 100%

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a `div` inside each `td` and apply `position: relative` over it.

[image]

```css
body {
    background-color: #afafaf;
}
.tbl-container{
    height: 1px;
}
.content {
    width: 500px;
}
.rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
     position: relative;
}
table tr td {
    color: #ffffff;
}
td>div{
    position: relative;
    background: #99b;
    height:100%;
}
td>div>span{
    background:#257;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    left:20px;
    top:15px;
    position:absolute;
}
td{
    height:50px;
}
.row-odd {
    background-color: #ff4e4e;
}
.row-even {
    background-color: #5bfc7a;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbl-container content rtl">
    <table>
        <tr class="row-odd">
            <td>Cell 1</td>
            <td>Cell 2</td>
            <td>Cell 3</td>
            <td>Cell 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-even">
            <td><div>Cell 1 <span></span></div></td>
            <td><div>Cell 2 <span></span></div></td>
            <td><div>Cell 3 <span></span></div></td>
            <td><div>Cell 4 <span></span></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Problem with inner div is that it won't fill the entire height of a cell, unless the table height is explicitly specified and in my case the table height depends on the content.

Comment: @ArturoO, I used a Technic for height problem in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474530/empty-space-coming-before-table-row-when-an-another-element-in-row-with-rowspan/48474734#48474734). See it (second sample code). I applied it to this answer to. You dose not need to specify height of table by my Technic.